# Access Denied to Tranquiliser Ammunition in Metal gear Solid V

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I am currently playing metal gear solid V.

I have developed several sniper rifles which put people to sleep instead of killing them.

However when I select either one of these for a mission there is a big '!' over the gun and there are no rounds.

Has anyone else encountered this and knows what to do?

Comment: Going on a mission with certain gear requires resources. Are you sure that you have enough?

Comment: What sort of resources are you talking about? What do you need for tranquilizer rounds?

Comment: Herbs like Digitalis and Haoma, if memory serves.

Comment: by chance are you doing some of the last challenge missions?

Comment: Ah so I need to collect more of those plants. That makes sense. I think it is mission 40